# actionscript - character escaping

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

In [XML document](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html), characters like carriage-return or quote gets escaped. I'm assuming it does it as described in [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/WD-xml-c14n-19991109.html#charescaping).

In the following code carrriage-return is replaced  by `&#xD;`

```
var str_carriage_return:String = "hello/rworld";
var xml_doc:XML = <node myattribute={str_carriage_return} />;
var xml_str:String = xml_doc.toXMLString(); //attribute value is hello&#xD;world
```

Is there a built in function in AS3 that can escape these characters in a string without creating XML document?

Comment: What do you want to escape them *for*? In general, when you use an API like an XML DOM you should not have to concern yourself with character escaping *at all*. The whole point of such an API is to transparently encapsulate these details so you don't have to care.

Comment: I'm dealing with situation where I `JSON.encode` a string that has a carriage-return, however when I try to `decode` it, it tells me that it's an invalid JSON string because it has a carriage-return.

Comment: And how does XML come into play here? Also, in JSON newlines in strings are encoded as `\n`, this should work both ways unless either your decode or your encode function behaves funny. Can you post an example of a broken JSON string?

Comment: I realize that was not the best way to ask the question. I just wanted to know if there is functionality that escapes characters just like XML object does.

Comment: But that's the point - you should not have to. Can you explain what you actually are trying to do?

Comment: I'm encoding a string `"hello/rworld"`. Encoded string I get is `"hello//rworld"` and when I'm trying to decode it, I get an error saying `String contains unescaped control character`

Comment: correction. backward slashes. encoding `\r` gives me `\\r`

Comment: Of course `'\r'` gives you `'\\r'`, the backslash is being escaped. Just don't insert the string `'\r'` insert an *actual* carriage return character.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not require it to be escaped per the W3C XML escaping specification then you can url encode your string instead...

```
var str:String = "Hello\r\nWorld!";
var escaped:String = escape(str); // Outputs: "Hello%0D%0AWorld%21"
var unescaped:String = unescape(escaped);
```

Check out the documentation for the [escape()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#escape%28%29) and [unescape()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#unescape%28%29) functions.